# SQL Server Database Design and Foreign Key confused

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, ssms, sql-server-2008

I need help to make my database design better.

The db design is from the old developer, now I'm trying to get the design better by trying to put foreign key around so there won't be any orphan table.

**CASE 1:**

Here is the story:

I have tables `ProductGroup` (PG), `ProductType` (PT), `Brand` (B), `Design` (D) to keep all specific detail of the item. Then all the four tables are assembled into one table `ProductMaster` (PM) where they will be joined and make a `ProdCd`.

When any row of the `PG,PT,B,G` is being deleted, all related rows in PM will also be deleted.

There is the sample of the table (The code will be simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductMaster](
    [ProdCd] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [GCd] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ACd] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [BCd] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CCd] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ProdType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BrandCd] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Design] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProdCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductGroup](
    [GCd] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [GroupDesc] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductType](
    [GCd] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ACd] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ProdType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TypeDesc] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GCd] ASC,
    [ACd] ASC,
    [ProdType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Brand](
    [GCd] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [BCd] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [BrandCd] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [BrandName] [varchar](75) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Brand] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GCd] ASC,
    [BCd] ASC,
    [BrandCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Design](
    [GCd] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [CCd] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [DesignCd] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [DesignDesc] [varchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Design] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GCd] ASC,
    [CCd] ASC,
    [DesignCd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The sample is:

- `ProductMaster` (`100010010001, 1, 0001, 001, 0001, PC-10 A, ZEN, PLAIN WHITE`)
- `ProductGroup` (`1, Finished Goods`)
- `ProdType` (`1, 0001, PC-10 A, Dinner Plate 10 Inch`)
- `Brand` (`1, 001, ZEN, ZEN`)
- `Design` (`1, 0001, PLAIN    WHITE, NO DECAL PLAIN WHITE`)

If I delete the `Design` row of `(1, 0001, PLAIN WHITE, NO DECAL PLAIN WHITE)`, the whole row in `ProductMaster` will be deleted.

**CASE 2:**

I have a table of transaction that have a Header and Detail. The detail only keep "ACd" from table "ProductType" where the "GCd" is always 1. When the PG,PT,B,G is modified, the record on the transaction also modified with "GCd" = 1.

The Table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PFHdr](
    [FNO] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [FMO] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [FDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [GCd] [int] NULL, *This is group related to the transcation not with the PM
    [IQtyc] [float] NULL,
    [RQtyc] [float] NULL,
    [TQtyc] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PFrmHdr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PFDtl](
    [FNO] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [ACd] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Input] [float] NULL,
    [Reject] [float] NULL,
    [Transfer] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PFrmDtl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FNO] ASC,
    [ACd] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The sample is:

- PFHdr(201211-00001,00001,2012-11-26,1,10,0,10)
- PFDtl(201211-00001,0001,5,0,5)
- PFDtl(201211-00001,0002,5,0,5)

If the ProductType record of `ProdType` (`1, 0001, PC-10 A, Dinner Plate 10 Inch`) being deleted, the record on PFDtl also deleted. But if the record `ProdType` (`7, 0001, PC-12 A, Dinner Plate 12 Inch`) deleted , the record on PFdtl did not changed.

Please help me, comment about the design,

1. How to make it better?
2. How to apply foreign key is possible?
3. Any suggestion of DB design?
4. In CASE 2, should I add column "GCd" to be able to use foreign key?
5. If the ProdType on ProductType must be unique, should I use it as
   primary key (with GCd and  ACd) or I just need putting UNIQUE or not
   putting any restriction

**NOTE:**

1. The old design do not have any foreign key, all is application restricted
2. I add Second Case

Comment: your design seems ok to me. The question is can you use foreign keys now? If you can then its ok. But if you cannot , then you need to use trigger.

Comment: As I can see there are quite a few basic design flaws, especially with assigning primary keys. Are the primary keys already assigned like that or you are planning to assign those in this way?

Comment: Well the design is made as is, and simply "to be able to work". The primary keys is like that, I want to change anything that might be needed if it can improve things and decrease or make no orphan table/records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two questions here.  Are foreign keys present?  If the foreign keys are present, are they declared?  As I read your schemas, there are some foreign keys in there such as ProductMaster.GCd.  They just aren't declared.

The advantage of declaring a foreign key is that it constrains the data to prevent loss of "referential integrity", a situation where an instance of a foreign key refers to a non existent primary key.  This is called "orphaned references". In general, the advantages of enforcing referential integrity are overwhelmingly larger than the cost of having the DBMS check integrity at insert time, and the extra programming needed to deal with rejected data.

If you want to add referential integrity constraints to an existing database,  you may have to locate and deal with "orphaned references" before the DBMS will let you put in the constraint.  This will generally involve lots of use of the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" construct.

Too bad the previous developer didn't declare foreign keys at the outset.

Comment: Nope, they don't declare any foreign keys before, because they think there won't be any orphan if controlled via application which proved wrong. Ok, then I will need to hunt the orphan down...  On the second case, should I put GCd on the table or not to be able to put foreign key?

Comment: Application code failed to prevent an orphaned foreign key? I'm shocked. Shocked, I tell you.

Comment: There are thousands upon thousands of application programmers who have thought they were careful enough to avoid data errors as completely as the DBMS can enforce constraints. A couple of dozen of those programmers have been right. The rest have been exposed to a learning exerience with a very high tuition rate. It's a shame that so many people dive into database building without learning how to do it right.

Comment: Whether or not you should put in a foreign key depends on the information requirements. Do you have a conceptual model of the database? A conceptual model expresses values and attributes in terms of subject matter entities and relationships among those entities. Once you have the conceptual model, the relationships pretty much determine where the forign keys ought to go. If you have no conceptual model, perhaps you can make one by reverse engineering the existing database. Good luck.

Comment: I already finished making the conceptual model, and found flaws here and there. Which is handled by application but I want it to be handle by foreign key, because some of the item being modified inside transaction... I should add the primary key of primary to make foreign key table?